# how to insert php variables inside the form action

Tags: php, html

i need to create a form which can be insert a php variable inside the action
the example is here

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="order_cart.php?id=<?php echo '$.prod_diay.' ?>" >
```

Comment: How are you getting to the form -from a link or something?
You could use `$_GET['prod_diay']` If you needed to get `prod_diay` from the url or something. Or what you have (should) work?

Comment: What's the problem? `<?php echo '$.prod_diay.' ?>"` looks weird - did you want to use `<?php echo $prod_diay; ?>"`

Comment: Is `$.prod_diay.` supposed to be a variable? It shouldn't have `.` in it.

Comment: Learning basic PHP string syntax would help: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="order_cart.php?id=<?php echo '$.prod_diay.' ?>" >
```

becomes

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="order_cart.php?id=<?php echo $prod_diay ?>" >
```

Notice the quotes missing around $.prod_diay.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quotes around a variable, and not sure what the . are for?

```
<?php echo '$.prod_diay.' ?>
```

Do like this instead,

```
<?php echo $prod_diay; ?>
```

Comment: it's cargo-cult programming. throw on EVERYTHING seen in other programs and hope something will work.

Answer (score 0):

how you currently have the php insert, its not actually echoing the variable contents, just the variable name, try this:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="order_cart.php?id=<?php echo $prod_diay; ?>" >
```