# Accessing a variable outside of an if statement

Tags: php, html

I am creating a forum and people can create a topic(e.g. movies) and a subtopic under the topic(e.g. Avengers). In the topic.php page when someone clicks on the subtopic they want to view the get sent to that page and the subtopic name gets sent also like this:

```
<a href='subtopic.php?sub_name=$sub_topic_name'>" . $sub_topic_name . "</a>
```

and this is how I get the value of the subtopic:

```
$sub_name = isset($_GET['sub_name']) ? $_GET['sub_name'] : $sub_name = 0;
```

When I'm on the page of the subtopic and I do a `var_dump` and `echo` of the topic and subtopic everything comes back good. But when I enter a value into the text area and click the add comment button, the name of the subtopic doesn't get uploaded to the database. Instead the value of `0` goes into the DB instead of the subtopic name.

For some reason the variable `$sub_name` doesn't work inside of the if statement. Can someone help me figure out the problem here ?

```
<form action="subtopic.php" method="POST">

        <textarea id="add_comment" required rows="8" cols="70" name="add_comment" 
        placeholder="Add comment about topic"></textarea><br><br>

        <button type="submit" id="add_button" name="add_button">Add Comment</button>

</form>
```

And the php code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(-1);

include 'includes/bootstrap.php';

$userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$sub_name = isset($_GET['sub_name']) ? $_GET['sub_name'] : $sub_name = 0;

global $sub_name;

$display_sub_topics = $con->prepare('SELECT topic, created_by FROM subtopic WHERE sub_topic = ?');
$display_sub_topics->bind_param("s", $sub_name);
$display_sub_topics->execute();
$display_sub_topics->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $display_sub_topics->num_rows;
$display_sub_topics->bind_result($topic, $created_by);
$display_sub_topics->fetch();

if (isset($_POST['add_button'])) {

    $comment_add = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic_replies (reply, added_by, subtopic) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $comment_add->bind_param("sss", $_POST['add_comment'], $userLoggedIn, $sub_name);
    $comment_add->execute();
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

var_dump($topic);
var_dump($sub_name);
```

Comment: `$sub_name = 0` should just be `0`. `global $sub_name;` has no effect outside a function definition.

Comment: `$_POST['add_button']` is set when you submit the form. The form doesn't have `?sub_name=` in the action URL, so `$_GET['sub_name']` won't be set.

Comment: `$sub_name = isset($_GET['sub_name']) ? $_GET['sub_name'] : $sub_name = 0;` should be written as `$sub_name = $_GET['sub_name'] ?? 0;`. It is much simpler

Comment: @Barmar I tried this `<form action="subtopic.php?sub_name=" method="POST">` and `<form action="subtopic.php?sub_name=$sub_name" method="POST"> but neither of them work

Comment: `action="subtopic.php?sub_name=<?php echo $sub_name; ?>"`

Comment: @Barmar wow thanks. Do you want to put it as an answer ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330264/how-to-insert-php-variables-inside-the-form-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form you're restarting the script, and variables from the previous invocation do not persist (except for session variables).

You can add the subtopic name to the action URL:

```
<form action="subtopic.php?sub_name=<?php echo urlencode($sub_name); ?>" method="POST">
```